# Deploying apps to employees testing using InTune 30 day trial

Tags: intune

My employer uses InTune to manage company mobile devices. As yet, we have not deployed any apps using InTune.

However, we have developed an app for internal employee use, for iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.1 and 10).

I was trying to test the roll out myself (I don't have access to the Corporate Outlook Admin account) so I set up a 30 day trial of InTune.

I have a few questions :

1. It looks like I would need a Enterprise Mobile Code from Symantec to apply to the Windows Phone app before I can delpoy with InTune? (I think I will have to skip this as I can't spend $300 on a test!)
2. Also, I believe both Android and iOS apps need to be 'wrapped' to be able to deploy to such devices?
3. Having wrapped them, can I then distribute them to devices using the trial InTune?
4. Do Windows Phone apps also need wrapping, or can they be distributed as is?

The purpose of this exercise is to prove apps can be rolled out through InTune, and what steps need to be taken to do this.

Note : the app is for employees only and should not therefore be available on the public app stores.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. A Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate is required before you deploy this app to users. You will need this certificate to generate an Application Enrollment token (AET) and sign company apps. Please refer to this guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/05/01/windows-phone-8-steps-to-acquire-an-enterprise-mobile-code-signing-certificate-required-to-sign-lob-or-company-apps/) for more details.
2. I think you may have some misunderstanding here. There're two kinds of tools called **Intune App warpping Tool** and **Intune App SDK**. They are used for enabling the MAM (mobile application management) features to your app. In other words, you still can deploy your app via Intune even the app hasn't been wrapped or developed with SDK. However, in this case the MAM features like restricting copy & paste operations to the un-managed apps.

   **Note** that the Intune App Wrapping Tool and Intune App SDK only support **Android** & **IOS** platforms. It depends on your needs to choose from these two tools. Simply to say, using Intune App Wrapping tool you don't need to access the app's source code but it supports less MAM features compared with Intune APP SDK, it also does not support warpping the apps on the public app store. Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/deploy-use/decide-how-to-prepare-apps-for-mobile-application-management-with-microsoft-intune) to know more detailed introductions about these two tools.
3. Yes of course.
4. No, as note above. The MAM policies only support IOS and Android devices at this moment. You can only use the feature called **Windows Information Protection** (WIP) to achieve the similar functions on Windows 10 desktop and mobile platform. More details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/protect-enterprise-data-using-wip).